# Combine single page tiffs into multipage tiff using a batch script

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick, batch-processing, tiff, irfanview

I have a document scanner that can only scans to single page tiffs and I need to combine them into multipage tiffs. I know Irfanview can do this, however I am open to other options.

Input, `C:\Scans`:

> ```
> 20161001115151800_0001.tif
> 20161001115151800_0002.tif
> ...
> up to
> ...
> 20161001115151800_0021.tif
> ```

...and...:

> ```
> 20161002130918260_0001.tif
> 20161002130918260_0002.tif
> ...
> up to
> ...
> 20161002130918260_0025.tif
> ```

Desired Output, `C:\Output`:

> ```
> 20161001115151800.tif
> 20161002130918260.tif
> ```

I am seeking a solution similar to [Bulk Combine TIFFs Based on Common File Name Using Irfanview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629142/bulk-combine-tiffs-based-on-common-file-name-using-irfanview) and [ImageMagick: how to batch combine multiple TIFF file to a single TIFF file in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619858/imagemagick-how-to-batch-combine-multiple-tiff-file-to-a-single-tiff-file-in-a) however I cannot figure out how to implement the first solution as a batch file with my file structure, and the second solution uses sequential filenames which I cannot produce.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried, what do you have trouble with? Please share your efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In program files folder of *IrfanView* there is the text file `i_options.txt` listing and explaining the available command line options. Examples for creating multi-page TIFF files are also included in this file.

I suggest to use additionally the option `/tifc=X` after `/cmdexit` in the *IrfanView* command line in the batch code below to define the compression to use for the multi-page TIFF file(s).

```
@echo off
if not exist "C:\Output\" md "C:\Output"
for %%I in ("C:\Scans\*_*.tif") do (
    for /F "delims=_" %%J in ("%%~nI") do (
        if not exist "C:\Output\%%J.tif" (
            "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" /cmdexit "/multitif=(C:\Output\%%J.tif,C:\Scans\%%J_*.tif)"
        )
    )
)
```

The `/multitif` option is enclosed in double quotes to avoid the need of escaping the parentheses and getting the entire option passed to *IrfanView* as one parameter string even if the name of current file contains a space character or another character which usually requires the usage of surrounding double quotes. Run in a command prompt window `cmd /?` and read at least last paragraph on last page in output help about usage of double quotes.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`

Comment: Mofi, I sincerely appreciate your response. It worked perfectly! As you suggested, I did use the /tifc command to compress the combined tiff. Thank you!